# CHILD_SA not working since proposed PFS Group is not configured

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, vpn, ipsec

Would be nice if someone could give me a hint.

## Intro

So I want to connect with my Kubuntu 18.04.5 client (NetworkManager - Strongswan/Charon) to my IPsec-IKEv2 (pfsense) Server, which works but after some time the VPN connection gets lost and I have to reconnect.

### Details

Most probably this is a consequence of the server side set PFS key group in Phase 2, which I set to 20 (nist ecp384).

```
charon-nm: 09[ENC] parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA request 160 [ N(REKEY_SA) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA No KE TSi TSr ]
charon-nm: 09[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
charon-nm: 09[CFG] received proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_256/AES_XCBC_96/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_GCM_16_128/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_GCM_16_256/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ
charon-nm: 09[CFG] configured proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_128/AES_CBC_192/AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/AES_XCBC_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
charon-nm: 09[IKE] no acceptable proposal found
charon-nm: 09[IKE] failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
charon-nm: 09[ENC] generating CREATE_CHILD_SA response 160 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
```

[This is apparanetly similar to DH Groups in Phase 1.](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/troubleshooting/ipsec.html#phase-2-pfs-mismatch)

So according to my understanding after these 160 *CREATE_CHILD_SA* requests - which the server sends, but the client declines - the server kills the connection.

Consequently the NetworkManager closes the connection as the vpn/tunnel is server side canceled.

```
charon-nm: 01[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 161 [ D ]
charon-nm: 01[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c20484b4
charon-nm: 01[IKE] closing CHILD_SA VPN_NAME{287} with SPIs cb865a87_i (47815624 bytes) c20484b4_o (6028589 bytes) and TS 10.1.3.1/32 === 0.0.0.0/0
charon-nm: 01[IKE] sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI cb865a87
charon-nm: 01[IKE] CHILD_SA closed
charon-nm: 01[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 161 [ D ]
charon-nm: 01[NET] sending packet: from <clientIP>[49309] to <serverIP>[4500] (69 bytes)
charon-nm: 12[IKE] deleting IKE_SA VPN[3] between <clientIP>[<username>]...<serverIP>[<servername>]
charon-nm: 12[IKE] sending DELETE for IKE_SA VPN_NAME[3]
charon-nm: 12[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL request 6 [ D ]
NetworkManager[947]: <warn>  [1607267447.9875] vpn-connection[0x55fd637ce510,45f0ac29-9f8f-46d6-adbe-e9e10e0ec5e3,"VPN_NAME",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
charon-nm: 12[NET] sending packet: from <clientIP>[49309] to <serverIP>[4500] (65 bytes)
NetworkManager[947]: <info>  [1607267447.9875] vpn-connection[0x55fd637ce510,45f0ac29-9f8f-46d6-adbe-e9e10e0ec5e3,"VPN_NAME",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
NetworkManager[947]: <info>  [1607267447.9876] vpn-connection[0x55fd637ce510,45f0ac29-9f8f-46d6-adbe-e9e10e0ec5e3,"VPN_NAME",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

As there are many intertwined parts I am unsure where I should enable this PFS group.

To my understanding [NetworkManager is more or less the interface between the GUI for the underlying OS/software packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) aka. [strongswan which in responsible for IPsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrongSwan) and [charon which is taking care of the IKEv2 keying](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon).

- *NetworkManager* stores its connection specific information in */etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_Name*
- *strongswan* uses the configuration set in:

  - [*/etc/ipsec.conf*](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IpsecConf) and
  - [starting with version 4.2.1](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/strongswan.conf.5.html) in [*/etc/strongswan.conf*](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/StrongswanConf)
  - starting with version 5.1.2 it additionally uses **.conf* files from the directory [*/etc/strongswan.d/*](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/StrongswanDirectory)
- and *charon* uses configurations set in:

  - */etc/strongswan/charon*.conf*
  - */etc/strongswan/charon/*.conf*

So maybe you have encountered a similar problem with DH/PFS groups and could tell me (*confused human being*) where I should put which configuration.

### Update:

[As proposed by @ecdsa](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298405/871938) I changed the config to the `[vpn]` section of the file */etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VPN_Name*:

```
proposal=yes
ike=aes256-sha256-ecp384
esp=aes256-sha256-ecp384
```

It seemed to be working fine (for some time):

```
charon-nm: 06[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 19
charon-nm: 06[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 19
```

but sadly after a while it stopped working and the previously mentioned sequence followed again breaking the connection.

```
charon-nm: 14[ENC] parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA request 20 [ N(REKEY_SA) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA No KE TSi TSr ]
charon-nm: 14[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
charon-nm: 14[CFG] received proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_CBC_256/AES_XCBC_96/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_GCM_16_128/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ, ESP:AES_GCM_16_256/ECP_384/NO_EXT_SEQ
charon-nm: 14[CFG] configured proposals: ESP:AES_CBC_128/AES_CBC_192/AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/HMAC_SHA2_384_192/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/AES_XCBC_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
charon-nm: 14[IKE] no acceptable proposal found
charon-nm: 14[IKE] failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
charon-nm: 14[ENC] generating CREATE_CHILD_SA response 20 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
```

## TL;DR

Where do you configure the DH/PFS group for IPSec IKEv2 in an Kubuntu client utilizing NetworkManager?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use a DH group during CHILD_SA rekeying, you have to change the proposal on the client. In strongSwan's GNOME NetworkManager plugin (developed upstream) there is an option for it. Not sure if the Plasma GUI (not developed upstream) provides one too. If not, you could try to manually configure the proposal in the NM config file (set `proposal=yes` and `esp=<proposal>`, e.g. `esp=aes256-sha256-ecp384`).

You could also make the DH exchange optional on the server by configuring a proposal without DH group, or adding `modpnone` to the existing proposal(s).